# How to Create None Value into Python Pandas

Tags: python

```
        a= []
        for item in soup2.findAll("div", class_='x'):
            where_to_watch = item.find_all('b')
            watch_at.append(x)
            
        dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = a)
        dataFrame.to_excel('x.xlsx')
        print(dataFrame)
```

Hello Guys How can i add "text" when the value is none? or maybe add NAN value...

Comment: show how `watch_at` look like?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest empty lists? watch_at = []

Comment: If `where-to_watch` is **None** then it will be added to the List `watch_at` as None and then will appear in the DataFrame as `NaN`. So where is the problem?

Comment: Fixed it already i just added the new = dataFrame.fillna("NO DATA") fill na method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `fillna()` method to achieve your goal. It would look like that:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.fillna("text")
dataFrame.to_excel('watch.xlsx')
```

Also there's a function called `isna()`. You could use it like that:

```
if pd.isna(where_to_watch):
    where_to_watch = "text"
watch_at.append(where_to_watch)
dataFrame.to_excel('watch.xlsx')
```